# How to use Knexjs synchronously on Apollo GraphQL Server

Tags: apollo-server, knex.js

How can I use [Knexjs](http://knexjs.org/) to fetch data synchronously on a resolver in [Apollo GraphQL Server](https://www.apollographql.com/)? For instance, if I run the following query:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        MySchema: (_, args, { dataSources }, info) => { 
            var result = db.knex.select('*')
                .from('SomeTable')
                .where({SomeColumn:'SomeValue'})
                .then(function(rows) {console.log(rows)})
                .catch(function(error) {console.error(error)});

           // Do something with the result here..
           console.log(result);
           return db.knex.select('*').from('SomeOtherTable')
        }
    }
}
```

The line `console.log(result);` just displays a `Promise {<pending>}` and by the time the line `.then(function(rows) {console.log(rows)})` is executed (asynchronously), the main function will be already finished.

Is there a way to get the result of the database query instead of a Promise on line `console.log(result);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your request to run synchronously and wait the result you need to add async/await

```
MySchema: async (_, args, { dataSources }, info) => { 
    var result = await db.knex.select('*')
                       .from('SomeTable')
                       .where({SomeColumn:'SomeValue'})
    // result is now a value and not a promise
    console.log(result)
}
```

As you noticed, I removed the .then and the .catch that are not relevant anylonger.

I highly recommend adding a try/catch around your awaited promise to avoid uncaught error.

```
MySchema: async (_, args, { dataSources }, info) => { 
    try {
        var result = await db.knex.select('*')
                           .from('SomeTable')
                           .where({SomeColumn:'SomeValue'})
        // result is now a value and not a promise
        console.log(result)
    } catch (e) {
        // handle e
    }
}
```

By the way, the `return db.knex.select('*').from('SomeOtherTable')` would benefit an await aswell to return data instead of a promise.